# Informatica Facebook connection

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, informatica, informatica-powerexchange

I have a little problem. I have installed Informatica server on Guest VM that has hostname info-hadoop with bridge network(in mean that other Computers in LAN can see and use it without any extra NAT rules). 
On computer that use Informatica server in /etc/hosts was added

```
IP info-hadoop
```

To create Facebook connection i followed official manual and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6P0OfwU2QbM) .

Here i got problem with Valid OAuth redirect URIs. Under

```
https://info-hadoop:8443/ows
```

i have such OAuth Callback URL:

```
https://info-hadoop:8443/ows/jrs/callback
```

But i can't enter this URL in

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/myappID/settings/advanced/
```

Facebook doesn't allow to save this URL. So i tried to use such link

```
https://info-hadoop.com:8443/ows/jrs/callback
```

With proper added lines on /etc/hosts:

```
IP info-hadoop info-hadoop.com
```

But facebook throws exception(in video at 3:30)

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application Configuration
```

What should i do?

Comment: Is it possible to use local domains? I'd like to get data from facebook and analyze the local. Without any extra domains.

Comment: No. Access have only computers in LAN. I try to make data stream like tweet stream. But i don't really understand how does it works.

Comment: 1) I don't  understand how can I create connection to Facebook without extra website/domain.
2) I don't  understand how Facebook streaming works.

Comment: 1) I think PowerExchange for Facebook requires it and there is no way around it. 2) Please post a separate question.